# How to add button in django admin site?

Tags: django, admin

I do want to know how to add button in django admin site.I tried many stuff but I couldn't able to do the stuff.I want to add a reset button for an attribute in the model where it should regenerate the value for the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to edit the admin files to add this button, it may be easier to inject a piece of JavaScript code and a button into the admin template to reset the form fields.

Comment: whether I want to create a new file with name forms.py and then customize it or I can able to do with default admin.py file and how?